# How to customize a section of cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is there a way to customize a section of cell? Probably the easiest way is to design a cell in the storyboard but I do not know how to implement it in my code.

This is what I got so far. It is pretty basic and copied from a tutorial on youtube. So sectionData should be replaced with the input for the customized section/subCell.

[The upper cell should be the 'mainCell' and the cell below should be displayed after the mainCell is touched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsjS6.png)

```
import UIKit

struct cellData {
var opened = Bool()
var title = String()
var sectionData = [String]()
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var tableViewData = [cellData]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableViewData = [cellData(opened: false, title: "Title1", sectionData: ["Cell1","Cell2","Cell3"]),
                     cellData(opened: false, title: "Title2", sectionData: ["Cell1","Cell2","Cell3"]),
                     cellData(opened: false, title: "Title3", sectionData: ["Cell1","Cell2","Cell3"]),
                     cellData(opened: false, title: "Title4", sectionData: ["Cell1","Cell2","Cell3"])]
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableViewData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableViewData[section].opened == true {
        return tableViewData[section].sectionData.count + 1
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let dataIndex = indexPath.row - 1

    if indexPath.row == 0  {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
        return cell
    } else {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].sectionData[dataIndex]
        return cell
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section )
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
        } else {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section )
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/](http://Tutorial)

you can follow this tutorial. You can reload the cell which you want to expand using below code. I have added in the `didSelectRowAt. Set expandCell variable to true for changing height of cell when reloading.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     // Expand View 
     self.expandCell = true 
     self.tableView.beginUpdates()
     self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
     self.tableView.endUpdates()
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == expandRowIndex && self.expandCell {
          return 200
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }
```

but the question you asked is irrelevant to the once you want to implement. anyway the answer for your question is, you can implement `viewForHeaderInSection` and `viewForFooterInSection` to customize your tableview sections.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = "create your custom cell here or you can init from your nib"
        return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}
```

if you want to do it in storyboard, just drag and drop UITableViewCell inside your tableview, assign some reuserIdentifier. call this tableview cell in your `viewForHeaderInSection`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! So shall I  implement the mainCell as a header and the subCell as the footer?

Comment: the best solution is, if you have main and subCell, then you can achieve this effect by having one cell, on tap adjusting the height of the cell to show the subCell. working with header and footer is unnecessary in your case. just have cell, adjust a height of the cell on tap with animation.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClrSpJ3txAs